# SharePoint Online Global Navigation In New List Experience

Tags: sharepoint-online, global-navigation

In Global Navigation text is not highlighting when viewing in New List Experience.

[image]

Whereas in Classic Experience text is highlighting as shown below.

[image]

Is this a bug in New Experience?